# Fit/scale 2d line in a given square

Tags: python, coordinate-system, s2sphere

I have the below python code sample using the s2sphere library to create a bounding box around a rectangle in latitude-longitude space:

```
for line in self.polylines:
    for latlng in line:
        bbox = bbox.union(s2sphere.LatLngRect.from_point(latlng.normalized()))
```

How can I do the exact same thing but instead just for a simple 2D line? To clarify (way out of my element here) I guess the question more broadly is in layman's terms: How can I fit a given set of coordinates forming a 2d line into a given square, effectively scaling the axis while keeping the shape. Hope that makes any kind of sense, it is for an art project and I didn't expect to run into math so early on.

The input is a a point on a sphere in latitute-longitude coordinates in the form `LatLng: 48.380124344,2.147867885` of the type *<class 's2sphere.sphere.LatLng'>*. What I want to achieve is the same, just without latitude/longitude information but with arbitrary points.

Another edit: I think the word is small multiples. I basically want to print many little graphs of varying elevation charts next to each other. They may be of vastly different scales, but i want to preserve the graphs general shape. matplotlib makes that easy, but I would like to understand the concept behind it. It very likely is easier than I think.

Here's a picture of what I want, the axis are just for clarification. What would I have to do to the source point in the global coordinates to get to the target point (note the changing local coordinates).
[image: Picture of desired output]

Comment: Can you please show (i) your input `latlng.normalized()`, (ii) some graphic, and (iii) your desired output?

Comment: I added some infos, hope they are what you wanted. I don't think I can reuse the latlng.normalized() for non-latitude, -longitude points.